# What does Akka Inbox actually do?

Tags: akka

What does Akka's `Inbox.create(actorsystem)` actually do? Will it create a new mailbox for all the actors as we have created the inbox on the system? And what does `inbox.watch(actorref)` do?

Can you explain what `inbox.send` and `inbox.receive` actually do?

Answer (score 4):

From the [source code](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.5.4/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/ActorDSL.scala#L117) for `Inbox`:

```java
/**
 * An Inbox is an actor-like object which is interrogated from the outside.
 * It contains an actor whose reference can be passed to other actors as
 * usual and it can watch other actors’ lifecycle.
 */
```

The `Inbox` object is a way to communicate with an actor from outside an actor. Let's say we wanted to send messages to and receive replies from an actor named `myActor`, and we wanted to do this from outside an actor. (The below code samples are adapted from the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.4/java/actors.html#the-inbox).)

```java
// this code is not inside an actor
ActorRef myActor = ???
final Inbox inbox = Inbox.create(system);
inbox.send(myActor, "ping");
```

`Inbox.create(system)` creates a system-level actor under the covers. `inbox.send(myActor, "ping");` sends the message `"ping"` to `myActor` with `Inbox`'s internal actor as the sender. Because the `Inbox`'s actor is the sender, it can get a reply from `myActor` with `inbox.receive`:

```java
try {
    assert inbox.receive(Duration.create(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)).equals("pong");
} catch (java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException e) {
    // timeout
}
```

`inbox.watch` registers the `Inbox`'s actor to be notified via [`DeathWatch`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.4/java/actors.html#lifecycle-monitoring-aka-deathwatch) when `myActor` has been terminated:

```java
inbox.watch(myActor);
myActor.tell(PoisonPill.getInstance(), ActorRef.noSender());
try {
    assert inbox.receive(Duration.create(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) instanceof Terminated;
} catch (java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException e) {
    // timeout
}
```

`Inbox.create(system)` does *not* create a new mailbox for all the actors in a system. Don't let the word "inbox" confuse you. Also, Akka enables by default a [dispatcher](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.4/java/dispatchers.html#types-of-dispatchers) that creates one mailbox per actor; the `Inbox` object doesn't change that.

Comment: That was an awesome explanation thanks.Now i have got the clarity

Comment: I was trying some examples with the inbox concept.but i am getting some below errors

Comment: I was trying some examples with the inbox concept.but i am getting some below errors when i am calling inbox watch for the target actor
java.lang.InterruptedException at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1245)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.tryLock(ReentrantLock.java:442) at akka.actor.UnstartedCell.sendMessage(RepointableActorRef.scala:219)